# Making child class inherit methods from parent in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter and OOP. I've been trying to make child class inherit some methods from parent class because I'd have repeated code if I didn't do it like that. But I've stumbled on a problem, caused probably by my limited knowledge of Tkinter and OOP.

Here is my code: (it's really simplified, but it is enough to solve problem in complete build):

**main.py**

```
from app import App
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Title")
    root.minsize(300, 300)
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

**app.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from smalerscale.test import FormFill


class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # notebook variable
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.note1 = FormFill(self)

        self.notebook.add(self.note1, text='From')
        self.notebook.pack()
```

**form_parent.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class FormParent(tk.Frame):
    """Form frame """

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.main_message = tk.Label(self, text="Some text").pack(fill='x', padx=50, pady=5)



    def print_something(self):
        print(self.main_message)
```

**test.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class FormFill(FormParent):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(self)

        print("It works maybe!")

        self.print_something()
```

And this is the error I get (something gets printed out, but no window appears):

```
It works maybe!
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kryst/PycharmProjects/covidForm/smalerscale/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
  File "C:\Users\kryst\PycharmProjects\covidForm\smalerscale\app.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.notebook.add(self.note1, text='Formulář')
  File "C:\Users\kryst\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 844, in add
    self.tk.call(self._w, "add", child, *(_format_optdict(kw)))
_tkinter.TclError: can't add .!app.!formfill.!formfill as slave of .!app.!notebook
```

I'm pretty sure I messed up the `__init__` and some attributes, but I can't find a way to make it right and working.

I'd be really grateful for any help.

Comment: `self.note1 = FormFill(self)` -> `self.note1 = FormFill(self.notebook)`

Comment: @JacksonPro Still, I get the same error

Comment: `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs) super().__init__(self)` in `FormFill` class -> `super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: can we have smalerscale to test the entirecode ???

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by that question

Comment: found Formfill in test.py is it the right one ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working answer by [@JacksonPro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12198502/jacksonpro)

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs) super().__init__(self) in FormFill class -> super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
```